# How to avoid small separation lines above and below unordered list items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap in order to have a select-option like list.

How can I avoid the small separation lines above (as depicted) and below the list of list items? See screeshot:

[image: screenshot]

In the following is the code visible. It will be the easiest to have a look at the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/qqnkc9u3/3/

html:

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    D2ropdown
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a class="my2" href="#"><!--data-value="action"--> Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="my2" href="#" data-value="another action">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="my2" href="#" data-value="something else here">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a class="my2" href="#" data-value="separated link">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
$(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').html($(this).text() + ' <span ></span>');
$(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').val($(this).data('value'));
});
```

css:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans');

#dropdownMenu1 {
/*text-indent: -150px;*/
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;

font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
/*font-style: italic;*/
color: red;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: left;

width: 242px;
height: 42px;
border: 4px;
/*background-color: #e7eaf3;*/
background: url("http://www.adelepham.com/deepthoughts/gray-pattern.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;
/*color: #5B629B;*/
/*padding: 4px;*/
}

.my2 {
text-indent: -7px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;

font-style: italic;
font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
color: red;
font-size: 18px;

-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
width: 242px;
height: 42px;
/*border: 4px;*/
/*color: #5B629B;*/
background: url("http://www.adelepham.com/deepthoughts/gray-pattern.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just get rid of the padding ([updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qqnkc9u3/5/)):

```
.dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0;
}
```

You can also do [this](https://jsfiddle.net/qqnkc9u3/9/):

```
.dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

to get rid of the little 1 or 2 px space between the button and the menu itself.

Answer (score 2):

Add     `padding: 0; margin: 0;` to your `#dropdown-menu`.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qqnkc9u3/7/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove padding and margin of the ul like:

```
.dropdown-menu {
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qqnkc9u3/8/